# inject java.sql.Time object into a bean - spring xml dependency injection

Tags: java, xml, spring, dependency-injection

I need to inject a `java.sql.Time` object into a `Subject` bean using xml based dependency injection.

This is my `Subject` class definition.

```
public class Subject{
    private java.sql.Time startedTime;
}
```

In Java code this will be the way to do it.

```
Subject subject = new Subject();
Time startedTime = Time.valueOf("HH:MM:SS");
subject.setStartedTime(startedTime);
```

But now I need to do the same injecting that `Time` object in the `Subject` bean via xml

```
<bean id="startedTime" class="mx.com.project.Subject">
<property name="startedTime">
<!-- java.sql.Time injection-->
</property>
</bean>
```

I've been looking for a while on the internet but have not found any example on this. Just one to inject a `Date` property into a `Customer` object by converting a formatted string `"yyyy-MM-dd"` to a `Date` object using `SimpleDateFormat.parse("yyyy-MM-dd")`

It makes me think there should be a similar way to convert a `String` to `Time` object. This is the example I found.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <bean id="dateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
        <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="customer" class="com.mkyong.common.Customer">
        <property name="date">
            <bean factory-bean="dateFormat" factory-method="parse">
                <constructor-arg value="2010-01-31" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

By the way, [the link to the above example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-how-to-pass-a-date-into-bean-property-customdateeditor/)

Answer (score 1):

Perform the conversion from String to Time in your object.

```
public class Subject
{
  private java.sql.Time startedTime;
  // blah.  your stuff.

  public void setStartedTimeValue(final String startedTimeValue)
  {
     startedTime = Time.valueof(startedTimeValue);
  }
}


<bean id="startedTime" class="mx.com.project.Subject">
  <property name="startedTimeValue" value="20:14:37"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: It seems like that's another valid way to do it. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

The first right answer to this question.

```
    <property name="startedTime">
        <bean factory-method="valueOf" class="java.sql.Time">
            <constructor-arg value="16:00:00" />
        </bean>
    </property>
```